# Question about two random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The random variables $X_1$ and $Y_1$
have the same distribution,the random variables $X_2$ and $Y_2$ also have the same distribution,
where $X_1$ and $X_2$ defined on $(\Omega_X,\mathcal{F}_{X},\mathbf{P}_X)$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ defined on $(\Omega_X,\mathcal{F}_{X},\mathbf{P}_X)$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ defined on $(\Omega_Y,\mathcal{F}_{Y},\mathbf{P}_Y).$ Dose  $\begin{pmatrix}
 X_1\\
X_2\end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix}
 Y_1\\
Y_2\end{pmatrix}$ have the same distribution ?

If $X_1$ is independent  with $X_2$ and $Y_1$ is independent with $Y_2$,then $\begin{pmatrix}
 X_1\\
X_2\end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix}
 Y_1\\
Y_2\end{pmatrix}$ must have the same distriution.Without the assumption of independent, dose  $\begin{pmatrix}
 X_1\\
X_2\end{pmatrix}$ and  $\begin{pmatrix}
 Y_1\\
Y_2\end{pmatrix}$ also have the same distribution ?

Comment: @geetha290krm$:$ I have overlooked that the random variables are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $X\sim N(0,1), X_1=Y_1=X_2 =X$ and $Y_2=-X$. This is a counter-example. ($-X$ has the same distribution as $X$ by symmetry).  [Note that $X_1+X_2=2X$ and $Y_1+Y_2=0$. This makes it clear that the joint distribtions are not equal].

Comment: +1 Thanks !  I don't know why downvote. If we only consider non-negative random variables,can we find some useful  counterexamples?

Comment: Yes, something very similar works. Take a non-negtiave r.v. $X$, $X_1=Y_1=X_2 =X$ and $Y_2$ to be indepdent of $X$ with the same distribution as $X$.  @user553010